# Can I visit the UK in the final week of my visa?

Tags: visas, uk, saudi-citizens

I'm from Saudi Arabia and I'm planning to visit UK next month but when I checked my visa it showed that it will expire in one month. So, Is it OK to make a journey in the last week of my visa? and make sure that I book my plane back before expiring date.

Comment: To clarify, you're a Saudi Arabian citizen (with passport) and your visa is valid for the next month?

Answer (score 6):

Yes it should be fine to visit the UK from Saudi Arabia the week before your visa expires. You must leave the UK by this date, unless you have successfully applied for permission to extend your stay. In some immigration categories, you cannot apply to extend your stay. They suggest that you apply for permission to extend your stay (if you are allowed to do so) at least 4 weeks before your visa's 'valid until' date.  You can arrive in the UK at any time up until the 'valid until' date, but remember that this is also the last day that you are permitted to stay in the UK.  Full details available [here](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/general-info/visa-holders/)

Comment: You should read the question of ["Do you need a visa?"](http://www.ukba.homeoffice.gov.uk/visas-immigration/visiting/general/visa/) otherwise your information is simply false.

Comment: @Karlson your are correct, thanks for pointing out my error, I failed to see Saudi Arabia on that list.  I have supplemented the response with an updated reference to the UK Border Agency.

Comment: To put it more clear, I'm planning to travel on Jan 31 and my vise will expire on Feb 8, so if I go back at anytime before Feb 8 I will be totally in safe. Thanks a lot for the complete answer.

Comment: Can you please confirm you are sure of this. I don't think this is correct. In most countries, you have the right to enter the country as long your visa is valid, the duration of the stay has nothing to do with the expiry date. After you enter, you can stay for as long as the duration of the stay is stated on the visa.  Why is the UK different?