# Going to UK for 1 night with only 3 days left on visa

Tags: visas, uk

I have been in/out visiting the UK.
I am planning to go to the UK again on August 24 just to join the one day tennis tournament and back to Ireland the next day, the 25th of August, but my UK visa will expire on August 26.
Is it still OK to visit the UK?

Comment: See http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/can-i-visit-the-uk-in-the-final-week-of-my-visa and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22769/can-i-visit-the-uk-in-the-final-week-of-my-visa

Answer (score 1):

It's fine and I have done staying until the last day of my visa before. Just make sure you get the date correct.